# Rss feed for game programmer?

Tags: graphics, rss, artificial-intelligence, feed

I was browsing [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119/what-are-the-best-rss-feeds-for-programmersdevelopers), which has good recommendation but a bit too general for me.

So, if anyone has a collection of nice game programming feeds,please share them. :)

(both general and specific topics are welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two I've used

[DirectX forum feed](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/dxgameprog/rss.aspx?AllPosts=1) and [Summary of interesting resources](http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheGeeksOf3d)

Answer (score 1):

I used http://www.gamedev.net/ in college a lot, especially the [NeHe Tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/)

Answer (score 1):

**AIGameDev.com:** http://feeds.aigamedev.com/AiGameDev

Answer (score 1):

GameDevKicks.com might become interesting over time - if used more:
http://www.gamedevkicks.com/